# Copy value from one datatable to another in Jbehave

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, bdd, jbehave

I need to copy data from one data table to another as mentioned below

When I enter company manager details of:

```
|NAME                      |VALUE                     |
|title                     |$randomList               |
|firstName                 |$random                   |
|initial                   |$random                   |
|surname                   |$random                   |
```

When I enter company employee details of

```
|NAME                      |VALUE                     |
|title                     |$randomList               |
|firstName                 |                          |
|initial                   |                          |
|surname                   |                          |
```

I am new to jbehave. In the above tables when i execute this scenario random characters will be generated and assigned to firstname,initial,surname in the 1st table I somehow need the same data when I execute the second table. I know we should parametrize by using examples table but in this case I don't want to use it. so how to copy the data from one table to another.

Comment: In what way do you put your random values into your first table? Are you doing it in the java code of your step?

Comment: yes i am doing in the java code